# java sqlite fetching entire table content

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database. Now I try to create a function, that fetches the entire table content and returns it as an Array or ArrayList or whatever.

How do I do that the best way?

Can I directly convert the cursor into an array of strings and add that to an arraylist? If so, how?

Should I create a map for each row the cursor traverses through, and add the strings into that, with their keys? I tried that, but it didn't work.

I haven't programmed anything in Java for many years.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why you want to fetch entire table data into memory?

Comment: just return a Cursor

Comment: Normally I work as webdeveloper, but out of curiosity I wanted to create a simple android app. So I wanted to fetch all table data to build an UI out of it for the app.

Comment: Then why aren't you using a cursor adapter?

Comment: as @CL said use a SimpleCursorAdapter,  it accepts a Cursor so you don't have to iterate over returned Cursor to build any array

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll check how that cursor adapter works.